# QUIMB Simple Update on MPS

Tags: python, quantum-computing

I am trying to run QUIMB's Simple Update Algorithm on an MPS. The first step I do is create a random MPS using the qtn.MPS_rand_state function. After this, I create the Local Hamiltonian required for the Simple Update method using the qtn.LocalHam1D function. With this one can run the Simple Update Algorithm as:

```
su = qtn.SimpleUpdate(
    psi0 = psi0,
    ham = ham_local,
    chi = 15,
    compute_energy_every = None,
    compute_energy_per_site = True,
    keep_best = True,
    progbar = True
)
for tau in [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]:
    su.evolve(200, tau=tau)
```

I have done this for PEPS using LocalHam2D instead and no execution errors happen, reaching correct ground state energies and ground states. Nevertheless, for MPSit does not run correctly.

The following error appears:

```
   
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱┃4  
 ┃ 
 ●
╱    
100%|##########| 200/200 [00:06<00:00, 29.16it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
***.ipynb Cell 8 line 7
     63 su = qtn.SimpleUpdate(
     64     psi0 = psi0,
     65     ham = ham_local,
   (...)
     70     progbar = True
     71 )
     72 for tau in [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]:
---> 73     su.evolve(200, tau=tau)
     75 print(f'Approximated ground state energy: {(su.best["energy"] * np.prod(n)):.6f}')
     77 # Continue with Full Update -> this doesn't improve the result at all, but it's really slow
     78 # fu = qtn.FullUpdate(
     79 #     psi0 = su.best['state'].copy(),
   (...)
     94 # plt.ylabel('Energy')
     95 # plt.xlabel('Iteration')

File ***\lib\site-packages\quimb\tensor\tensor_arbgeom_tebd.py:583, in TEBDGen.evolve(self, steps, tau, progbar)
    581     # possibly compute the energy
    582     if self.compute_energy_final:
--> 583         self._check_energy()
    584         self._update_progbar(pbar)
    586 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    587     # allow the user to interupt early

File ***\lib\site-packages\quimb\tensor\tensor_arbgeom_tebd.py:630, in TEBDGen._check_energy(self)
    628     en = self.compute_energy_fn(self)
    629 else:
--> 630     en = self.compute_energy()
    632 if self.compute_energy_per_site:
    633     en = en / self.ham.nsites

File ***\lib\site-packages\quimb\tensor\tensor_2d_tebd.py:333, in TEBD2D.compute_energy(self)
    330 def compute_energy(self):
    331     """Compute and return the energy of the current state.
    332     """
--> 333     return self.state.compute_local_expectation(
    334         self.ham.terms,
    335         **self.compute_energy_opts
    336     )

File ***\lib\site-packages\quimb\tensor\tensor_2d.py:4205, in TensorNetwork2DVector.compute_local_expectation(self, terms, max_bond, cutoff, canonize, mode, layer_tags, normalized, autogroup, contract_optimize, return_all, plaquette_envs, plaquette_map, **plaquette_env_options)
   4202     plaquette_envs = dict()
   4203     for x_bsz, y_bsz in calc_plaquette_sizes(terms.keys(), autogroup):
   4204         plaquette_envs.update(
-> 4205             norm.compute_plaquette_environments(
   4206                 x_bsz=x_bsz, y_bsz=y_bsz, **plaquette_env_options
   4207             )
   4208         )
   4210 if plaquette_map is None:
   4211     # work out which plaquettes to use for which terms
   4212     plaquette_map = calc_plaquette_map(plaquette_envs)

File ***\lib\site-packages\quimb\tensor\tensor_2d.py:3141, in TensorNetwork2D.compute_plaquette_environments(self, x_bsz, y_bsz, max_bond, cutoff, canonize, mode, layer_tags, first_contract, second_dense, compress_opts, **compute_environment_opts)
   3134         first_contract = "y"
   3136 compute_env_fn = {
   3137     "x": self._compute_plaquette_environments_x_first,
   3138     "y": self._compute_plaquette_environments_y_first,
   3139 }[first_contract]
-> 3141 return compute_env_fn(
   3142     x_bsz=x_bsz,
   3143     y_bsz=y_bsz,
   3144     max_bond=max_bond,
   3145     cutoff=cutoff,
   3146     canonize=canonize,
   3147     mode=mode,
   3148     layer_tags=layer_tags,
   3149     compress_opts=compress_opts,
   3150     second_dense=second_dense,
   3151     **compute_environment_opts,
   3152 )

File ***\lib\site-packages\quimb\tensor\tensor_2d.py:2934, in TensorNetwork2D._compute_plaquette_environments_y_first(self, x_bsz, y_bsz, max_bond, cutoff, canonize, layer_tags, second_dense, y_envs, **compute_environment_opts)
   2932 # first we contract from either side to produce column environments
   2933 if y_envs is None:
-> 2934     y_envs = self.compute_y_environments(
   2935         max_bond=max_bond,
   2936         cutoff=cutoff,
   2937         canonize=canonize,
   2938         layer_tags=layer_tags,
   2939         **compute_environment_opts,
   2940     )
   2942 # next we form vertical strips and contract from both top and bottom
   2943 #     for each column
   2944 x_envs = dict()

File ***\lib\site-packages\quimb\tensor\tensor_2d.py:2791, in TensorNetwork2D.compute_y_environments(self, max_bond, cutoff, canonize, dense, mode, layer_tags, compress_opts, envs, **contract_boundary_opts)
   2788 if envs is None:
   2789     envs = {}
-> 2791 self.compute_ymin_environments(envs=envs, **contract_boundary_opts)
   2792 self.compute_ymax_environments(envs=envs, **contract_boundary_opts)
   2794 return envs

File ***\lib\site-packages\quimb\tensor\tensor_2d.py:2529, in TensorNetwork2D.compute_environments(self, from_which, xrange, yrange, max_bond, cutoff, canonize, mode, layer_tags, dense, compress_opts, envs, **contract_boundary_opts)
   2527 if dense:
   2528     tn ^= first_row
-> 2529 envs[from_which, sweep[1]] = tn.select(first_row)
   2531 for i in sweep[2:]:
   2532     iprevprev = i - 2 * sweep.step

IndexError: range object index out of range
```

The problem arises after the entire set of steps for one specific tau. I believe it is due to the SimpleUpdate algorithm being defined for 2D systems. I also tried defining the MPS as a PEPS of size Nx1 with a LocalHam2D but the exact same problem occurs.

Any help would be largely appreciated, pretty new using QUIMB.

Thanks.

Comment: As you seem to be aware, while QUIMB can handle MPS, the SimpleUpdate algorithm has internal optimizations tailored for 2D systems (PEPS). The error occurs inside the compute_y_environments function within the tensor computation process. This indicates that an index is being used that exceeds the valid bounds of a range object, likely during tensor contractions or boundary calculations. Worth looking more into the PEPS side and less MPS.